# bode plot, zero at 0Hz

Tags: transfer-function, bode

I'm learning to draw magnitude bode plots from transfer functions:

$$ H(s) = \frac{sRC}{sRC+1} $$

So I can see that I have a zero at s = 0, which corresponds to 0 Hz. I know this will add a +20dB/dec slope for all frequencies in a logarithmic plot. I'm struggling to figure where the gain will start at the left side of my plot. I can kind of cheat a little bit because I know that this is a passive high pass filter, so I can start at the right side of the plot and call that 0dB, move to the left, and then apply my 20dB/dec slope once I pass the break frequency of the pole. But if the transfer function was more complicated and I didn't already know what to expect, what would I do?

Comment: Like Tim mentioned, you can start at a very small frequency value. Even industry standard applications draw the initial magnitude value at a frequency very close to 0 Hz. Unless you care about really granular values near 0 Hz, I wouldn't worry too much about what this value is since we usually look at the action as we move away from 0 Hz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$H(s) = \frac{R C s}{R C s + 1}$$

If $R C s$ is much lower than 1 (i.e., $R C s \ll 1$, in Math), then you can make an approximation: $$H(s) \simeq \frac{R C s}{1}$$

Basically, the effect of the $R C s$ in the denominator becomes insignificant.

So, just pick a radian frequency well below $1 / R C$ and compute the magnitude of $H(s)$ at that point -- mark that on your plot, and draw your line rising at 20dB/decade from there.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach:  Let's start with rewriting using $s = j \omega$ and $RC = 1/\omega_0$. We get
$$H(\omega) = \frac{j\omega}{j\omega+\omega_0}$$

Then we look at the most "relevant" frequency first. In this case that's $\omega = \omega_0$. At this frequency your magnitude is -3dB. For frequencies much larger then $\omega_0$ you simply have $|H(\omega)|=1$  and for frequencies much lower you get $-20dB$ per decade.

You can draw this as two straight lines than intersect at $\omega_0$ and than you round out the "knee" so that it goes through $-3dB$ at  $\omega_0$.

You can't really draw anything at  $\omega = 0$ since the log magnitude is minus infinity, so you are going to run out of paper or screen before you get there.

> But if the transfer function was more complicated and I didn't already know what to expect, what would I do?

You start with the most "interesting/relevant" frequencies and work your way up and down from there.